# How to let others tag text/images on their site with information from my MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
| Name    | Site Link          |
|---------|--------------------|
| Adam    | www.adamssite.com  |
| Simon   | www.simonssite.com |
| Angela  | angelassite.com    |
```

I want site owners to be able to copy a code to their site and put it under an image or text.

The code will be of a tagging system where others can input information from my MySQL database thus tagging information from my database to the chosen image or text on the site.

How do I begin to do this?

I have been going round in circles trying to plan a path, but I am unsure of how to start this.

Can anyone put me in the right path or show me the path I need to go down?

Comment: Like Facebook, Twitter and G+ buttons?

Comment: Yes so if there was an image/text and it was about 'Simon' people can tag 'Simon' in the tag input and the tag would be wrapped with the site link so people can click on the tag. Therfore taking them to www.simonspage.com

Comment: you need to make use of iframe where the iframe url contain your url path to the server side script that will handle the mysql request, based on the site link. example `<iframe src="yoursite.com/do/process/my-database.php?sitelink=www.adamssite.com&maybe-some-key=#@##"></iframe>`

Comment: Ah thanks thats that part sorted! So for the part where I need users to copy the taggin input code to their site, how do I do that? I will need to make a taggin input but how do I link up the possible tags to chose from the input from my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a javascript function code block, which can make request to your php code using post and getting results via a callback method. For example you can use JQuery's .post method :

```
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
 function(data){
   console.log(data.name); // John
   console.log(data.time); //  2pm
 }, "json");
```

instead of test.php you can have your own server file which will control the action of tagging. And instead of the simple callback method here which logs to console, you can have you own DOM manipulation code. And once inside PHP (or which language you are using) you can generate appropriate sql queries for tagging and retrieving information, using mysql_query() and mysql_fetch_assoc() and mysql_fetch_array().

Comment: Ah thanks! Is there a name for this kind of technique? So i can research it further?

Comment: it is simply called using ajax to get data from server, you can also look it up as http request using javascript too.

Comment: Ah thanks, so as they will be copying the taggin input bar code from my site to paste onto their site. What will that code look like? Will there be sensitive mysql information in that code?

Comment: @JamesMoore no there wont be, there will only be a div element with an id you specified and a script block for javascript to make the request to your server. They will not see anything about the db or the php code. But you must take care of php security like sql injections and etc.

Comment: Will that not mean they need to upload a file involving the php code for it to relate to it?